# Cannot resolve symbol 'search', when trying to declare an editText box to appear on a button click

Tags: java, android

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActivity);
    button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText) ;
                    search.setVisible(View.GONE);
                }
            }
    );
```

I get the error message, I'm still a beginner to android studio and I'm not sure how to get the editText declared so I can interact with it. This is in the onCreate.

Comment: You did not declare `search` as an EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

to

```
EditText search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

You forgot to declare the search `EditText` first.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it, I'm still getting a cannot resolve method error on the .setVisibility though, I thought fixing this would solve it but it doesn't.

Comment: Did you use `setVisible` or `setVisibility` ?